# CakePHP 3 - Configure route to allow optional parameter

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a route like this:

```
$routes->connect('/custom/url', [
    'prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'Things', 'action' => 'index'
]);
```

I want to allow an optional passed parameter so the URL can be `/custom/url/123` but also still allow it to not have the parameter at all, like `/custom/url`.

If I change the route to `/custom/url/:param` it throws an exception if I visit the URL without the extra parameter. How can I make the parameter matching lazy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

routes like:

```
$routes->connect('/custom/url/*', [
    'prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'Things', 'action' => 'index'
]);
```

**In controller**

```
public function index($param = null){
  // your code here
}
```