# CakePHP 3.4 and CakePHP v3.5 Parameterized routing

Tags: php, cakephp, routes, cakephp-3.0

I am making small project in cakePHP v3.5, i am not able to use parametrized in appropriate way. Also in some cases if we want to pass optional parameter in url then how can i do?

CakePHP v3.5

```
$routes->get('test/testfn/:param1/:param2', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'testfn']);

where 
test: Controller,
testfn: Method of TestController,
param1: Parameter 1,
param2: Parameter 2
```

All i did to get params from url to TestController,

```
  $this->request->getParam(param1)
  $this->request->getParam(param2)
```

How can i list all parameters that i passed from routes to My Controller instead of single param step by step.

OR anyone have better options to do routing in cakePHP v3.5

Also I am confused about the paramterized routing principle of cakePHP3.4
so, in that case if anyone has some solution to cakePHP v3.4.

Please Help me.

Thanks

Comment: In cake 3.4 Routing with params :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448765/cakephp-3-configure-route-to-allow-optional-parameter?rq=1

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking how to define routes or how to read route parameters.

Comment: @cgTag can you just explain how can we do parameterized routing in cakePHP3.5. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**In config/routes.php**

```
$routes->get(
            '/api/test/*', ['controller' => 'Api', 'action' => 'check']
    );
```

**In controller**

```
public function check($first=null, $sec=null) {

   pr($params);
   pr($sec);
   die;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Routes.php**

```
$routes->connect('/users/:id/edit/:type', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'edit', ['id' => '\d+', 'pass' => ['id', 'type'], '_name' => 'edit-client']);
```

In this route in ID is user id and Type is user type two parameter pass in this route

if this route method is **POST** then ex - `$this->request->getData('id');` and if this route method **GET** then ex -  `$this->request->getParam('id')`